# Getting the Graphviz2 dot input with large graphs

Tags: perl, graphviz

My Perl scripts generates a very large graph with the module GraphViz2

```
use GraphViz2;

my($graph) = GraphViz2 -> new
(
    edge   => {color => 'grey'},
    global => {directed => 1},
    node   => {shape => 'oval'},
);
add_very_many_nodes_and_edges(); # 600 nodes 6.5K edges
```

I would like to get the dot input before feeding this to graphviz . Accoding to GraphViz2 I need to graph->run before getting the graph->dot_input;

This process takes too long though.. Is there any otherway to get the dot input before the actual run enviroment ?

Bear in mind that this is possible when using the Graph::Easy module via the 
Graph->as_graphviz_file() method.